# Negative product prices in Admin Panel order

Tags: admin, sales

We process a lot of B2B orders (mostly by mail and phone) through the Magento Admin Panel, works fine, but what we are missing is an option to give a discount or extra fee to a customer.

In the ideal world we'd like to add an extra order line which has a custom description, custom price and a custom qty. This currently isn't possible because it expects a product.

To work around this we created a dummy product which can be added to the order, we change the price and qty and voila we have an extra order line. I've added a custom option (textfield) to the product which allows us to add a nice description for the customer.

This way we can add extra charges to the order, that's great. We also want to various discount order lines to the order. To do this I need to create order lines with a negative price in the admin panel.

Is there a relatively save modification to make to allow this?

Maybe as an alternative, maybe a custom discount could also be an option, but since this only allows for one discount to be added this isn't ideal. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Anyone help me, how can i give each product discount(Discount % display ) while creating manual order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to create a negative row in the order because the Magento core is full of code like `$value = max(0, $value)` when it's about prices. This doesn't mean it's not possible.

First you need to override this method: `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create::_parseCustomPrice`. THere is a line in there that checks if the price is at least 0. It needs to be removed.

```
price = $price>0 ? $price : 0;
```

The you need to look in the code for the text `max(` and see if the lines related to checkout.
For example there is this in `Mage_Tax_Block_Sales_Order_Tax::_initSubtotal`

```
subtotalIncl = max(0, $subtotalIncl);
$baseSubtotalIncl = max(0, $baseSubtotalIncl);
```

You may need to remove a lot of these kind of lines.
I don't know if this is the way to go but I'm sure it's possible.

What I would do in your place is to create a discount rule each time I need something like this with the full amount usable only once, with a strange coupon code, and apply it to your order. Not sure if this fits your needs (probably not) but this is what I got so far.

Comment: Why not operate after `collectTotals()`?

Comment: @pspahn. It could work, but the `collectTotals()` method is a really complex one. I thought that it could be easier to view it as a 'black box' (and maybe change some `min`, `max` calls) and just manipulate the data that goes in the 'black box' because I know the end result should be correct.

Answer (score 4):

This is unnecessary. The admin panel of Magento allows you to set custom product prices when placing orders from the backend:

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

All I needed to do was check "custom price" and click "update items and qtys".

Cheers.

Comment: I'm not following, this doesn't allow us to set a negative order line, it only allows us to set a different product price.

Comment: This fulfills your requirement for variable discounts and fees. You can increase the price as well. Not just discount. Create a new product called fee and add with variable pric. Sounds as if You've already made up your mind of how it should be accomplished, I'm giving you a no code admin based alternative.

Comment: Yeah in some way, this is the solution they currently use, but is too limited. :)  This offers a discount but doesn't allow me to enter a description for the discount and the custom prices aren't allowed to go below zero, which is a requirement in this case.

Comment: @philwinkle : Is possible to display both custom price and original price?

Comment: like same,,  can i give each product discount(Discount % display ) while creating manual order.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and do the following (Don't know whether this will work though...)

- Create a simple "discount product" with a price of 1 EUR
- Create a price rule that gives a 200% discount (Don't know whether this will work...) of the amount of the product.
- Whenever you add that product to the cart you can define the discount you want to give via qty.

Just a random idea that is worth a shot as it would require no coding at all...

Comment: I thought of this also, but It won't work. The "percent" rules are capped at 100 % discount : `$rulePercent = min(100, $rule->getDiscountAmount());`. I don't know the impact of removing this capping.

Comment: You could always clone the percent discount functionality and create your own "percent discount (uncapped)" to minimize the overall impact.

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished this on one of our sites which had discount and charge requirements due to the need to integrate to a custom CRM by extending the quote, order, invoice and credit memo items to include a discount and charge field.

I then added an input field for each into the item row on the edit page in the admin area.

The subtotal and tax total collectors needed to be over-ridden to take the discount and charge into account as well as the row total calculation on each of the items.  Including, but not limited to:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo_Total_Subtotal
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo_Total_Tax
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo_Item::calcRowTotal
```

Also,

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Order::prepareCreditmemo
Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Order::prepareInvoice
Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create::initFromOrder
```

All need to be over-ridden to move the extra fields around when orders are cancelled or invoiced.

All of the display points for the items need to be adjusted to take the charge and discount fields in to account.

All in all a pretty serious development undertaking, and not for the faint of heart, but it's workable.

Comment: Care to share your written code?

Comment: @paul-hachmang It's pretty bespoke to the build,  not a self contained module